# i can not get span value in blur function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create all span's text as like placeholder text using below code,

```
function placehodertype() {
   //alert((this.textContent || this.innerText));
    var textval=(this.textContent || this.innerText);
   if(textval=="Click and type!")
    {
        $(this).text("");
        $(this).focus();
    }
    $(this).blur(function(){

        alert();
        var textval2 =(this.textContent || this.innerText);

        //textval2 = textval2.length;
            alert(textval2);
        if(textval2=="")
         {
        $(this).text("Click and type!");
        //$(this).focus();
         }

    });
}

var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i = 0, len = spans.length; i < len; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = placehodertype;
}
```

its working fine but that span will disappear when user click on span and click outside without type anything.To avoid this problem i am getting that span text value using **blur()** but its shows like undefined error!.

Check my code  here :http://jsfiddle.net/Manivasagam/EHhbH/29/

why i am getting this? and I hope someone will update my code.

Comment: In the statement `var textval=(this.textContent || this.innerText);`, As per my understanding `this` referes to `Window` not `span` and thus your event is not working properly.

Comment: @Satpal yes you are right. so how can i get that clicked span text in blur?

Comment: Some suggestions I probably should have left for you are in the comments of the answer below lol

Comment: Have you tried looking at these - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206037/jquery-focus-and-blur-to-show-and-hide-a-message
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309092/jquery-div-hide-show-on-focus-issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426438/jquery-on-form-input-focus-show-div-hide-div-on-blur-with-a-caveat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        var span = document.createElement('div');
        span.idName = "editableid";
        span.innerHTML = ['<br><span style="color:red" class="insidespan" contenteditable="true" >Click and type!</span> '].join('<br> ');
        document.getElementById('placeHere').insertBefore(span, null);
      }

      $('#placeHere span.insidespan').on('click', function() {
        var textval = $(this).text();
        if (textval == "Click and type!") {
          $(this).text("");
          $(this).focus();
        }
      }).on('blur', function() {
        var textval = $(this).text();
        if (textval == "") {
          $(this).text("Click and type!");
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="placeHere"></div>
```

As you are already using jQuery, You can simply use

```
$('span').on('click', placehodertype);
```

instead of

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i = 0, len = spans.length; i < len; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = placehodertype;
}
```

You complete implementation can be written as

```
$('span')
    .on('click', function() {
        var textval = $(this).text();
        if (textval == "Click and type!") {
            $(this).text("");
            $(this).focus();
        }
    })
    .on('blur', function() {
        var textval = $(this).text();
        if (textval == "") {
            $(this).text("Click and type!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Not that there are any issues with your changes, it just bothers me that the blur event handler is being set via an onclick event handler. I would have separated them but that's just me.

Comment: @JonathanGray, I totally agree with you `that the blur event handler is being set via an onclick event handler.` even I would have seperated that

Comment: Random second thought after looking at your (much cleaner) code, I think focus should be used instead of click in order for the script to properly handle TAB-selecting (or however it's called)

Answer (score 1):

You have a big mess between native Javascript code and jQuery. Try this solution:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                for(var i=1;i<=3;i++) {
                    var $span = $('<span style="color:red" class="insidespan" contenteditable="true">Click and type!</span>');
                    $('#placeHere').append($span).append('<br/>');

                    $span.click(function(){
                        $(this).text('');
                    })
                    .blur(function() {
                        if($(this).text() == "") {
                            $(this).text("Click and type!");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="placeHere">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```